# Sending PHP generated HTML by PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to setup PHPMailer to send e-mails that consist mostly from PHP generated HTML (i.e dynamic tables made with data from a database, inside functions and even different classes). However most examples I've seen only have this method for adding content to the email body:

```
$mail->Body = $body;
```

which seems easy to implement for simple content and/or strings but not dynamic PHP content.

Is there some kind of way of adding content to the e-mail body by chunks or perhaps an entire PHP page? It seems like a really stupid question but I can't quite find a way to do it...

Comment: Generate the content however you need, then shove it in `$body`.

Comment: ->Body is just a string. you can build it up in chunks. e.g. `$m->Body = '<html>'; $m->Body .= 'long ugly chunk of html'; $m->Body .= '</html>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the content and put it in to a *buffer string*, then, you can set the *body* of **PHPMailer** with this.

Here an example:

```
ob_start();

// Include a file here or insert the code that generate the HTML
// Example
include('page.php');

$body = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$mail->Body = $body;
```